# Two threads in initializer on rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-sqs

Initially I was using one thread to listen a queue from amazon and works perfectly.

[image]

**aws.rb**

```
Thread.new do
    queue = AWS::SQS::Queue.new(SQSADDR['my_queue'])
    queue.poll do |msg|
    ...
```

but now I appended another thread to listen another queue:

```
...    
Thread.new do
    queue = AWS::SQS::Queue.new(SQSADDR['my_another_queue'])
    queue.poll do |msg|
    ...
```

and now it seems to not work. Only the last one receives response...

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Are you overwriting the variable `queue`?